# Unable to find source file

Tags: asp.net

While configuring IIS and deploying my Web Application , I did something in Visual Studio while trying to deploy project.
and all my code behind files dissapeared. I didn't delete them on purpose .
Who knows what is going on and what i can do?

Comment: Deployed using Visual Studio? In the deployed folder, all the code behind files would get compiled into assembly (dll). Check your actual solution source folder. Those all files will still be there.

Comment: Yes ,Visual Studio. No there are no lost files in my project folder. And yes i saw some dll files in temp folder how to build them to code behind files again>?

Comment: Have you published the web Application?????????

Comment: I did it but older version. Now it fires a mistake.

Comment: What you speak isn't making much sense. Sorry about that. Don't mean any offense thre. When you already have the code files in your project folder why do you mean by _how to build them to code behind files again?_. Probably you need to read about the web application creation, building, deployment and how it works etc.

Comment: Or if you have a specific problem, let us now What are you doing? What is the problem that is preventing you from moving forward? What is the next step that you want to do? etc., kind of information for the folks here in the community to help better.

Comment: Sorry it seems like i was unclear. I don't have any .cs and . config and .layout  files  in my folder which is `C:\Users\linklee\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\mykladr` but i saw some dll files in temporary .net folder which is `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mykladr\427545fc\512cbc26` i was talking about them and i asked is there a solution to take `App_Code.gm0xy44d.dll` for example and do something with it  may be parse i don't know to restore cs files back

Comment: it's a web application .Yesterday i just wanted to deploy and run my site in local network, but then something happened ( may  be i pressed something or i don't know and my source file like default.aspx.cs dissapeared but default.aspx for example still exists and now i want them back/